# Dart Polymer bind property

Tags: dart, polymer, web-component, dart-polymer

I want to switch pages using `neon-animated-pages`

So my code is simple:

```
<dom-module id="auth-view">
  <template>
    <style>
    </style>
      <neon-animated-pages class="neon-container" selected="[[selected]]">
          <login-page></login-page>
          <pwd-reset-page></pwd-reset-page>
      </neon-animated-pages>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

And in dart code:

```
@property
int selected = 0;

StreamSubscription _clickSubscription;

attached() {
  _clickSubscription = this.on['showPwdReset'].listen((e) {
    e = convertToDart(e);
    // Read things from `e`.
    print("Got show Event!");
    selected = 1;
  });
}
```

So, I catch the event - I can see that in console. But page does not change.

I still can change it manually with adding selected in shadow-dom.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The pageitems should be wrapped with `<neon-animatable>` 
like:

```
    <neon-animatable><login-page></login-page></neon-animatable>
    <neon-animatable><pwd-reset-page></pwd-reset-page></neon-animatable>
```

For more info https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/neon-animation/neon-animatable